# Xpages: Custom Controls with Property Groups and Multiple instances

Tags: xpages

Building a menu custom control and cannot get Property Groups with multiple instances to work.

My cc code is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">

    <xe:navigator id="navigator1"
        styleClass="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <xe:this.treeNodes>     
            <xe:repeatTreeNode indexVar="index" var="entry"
                value="#{javascript:compositeData.menuItemGroup}">
                <xe:this.children>
                    <xe:pageTreeNode
                        label="#{javascript:entry.menuName}">
                    </xe:pageTreeNode>
                </xe:this.children>
            </xe:repeatTreeNode>
        </xe:this.treeNodes>
    </xe:navigator> 
</xp:view>
```

My Xpage code is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">

            <xc:cc_CommonMenu xp:key="facetMenu" menuTitle="PCs">
                <xc:this.menutItemGroup>
                    <xc:menutItemGroup menuName="First Menu Item"
                        menuTarget="/firstMenuItem">
                    </xc:menutItemGroup>
                    <xc:menutItemGroup menuName="Second Menu Item"
                        menuTarget="/secondMenuItem">
                    </xc:menutItemGroup>
                </xc:this.menutItemGroup>
            </xc:cc_CommonMenu>
</xp:view>
```

I suspect it may be easier to do this by reading a data structure, something [similar to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26168228/xpages-custom-control-with-custom-property-group-that-allows-multiple-instances):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a little typo.

Your property group is called `menutItemGroup` - with a "t" between "menu" and "ItemGroup".

Change your code in your Custom Control to

```
value="#{javascript:compositeData.menutItemGroup}">
```

(with a "t" between "menu" and "ItemGroup") and it will work.

Comment: Yup that was it. Thanks!