# Xpages: Passing a JSON Object to a custom control to build a menu

Tags: json, xpages, custom-component

I want to make a reusable menu custom control. I am building a custom control that takes an object as its Type. Calling this [configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26168228/xpages-custom-control-with-custom-property-group-that-allows-multiple-instances).

I want to pass a JSON object for the menu, as this gives me structure with flexibility. I want to be able to have one level of containers, e.g. I may have a flat menu but also may have a twisty with submenus, like so.

[image]

I figure my first level menu object will be a container, with a parameter to indicate if it should actually be a container (like "By Date" below) or just a flat menu (like the first 4 menus). In the navigator control the container has a property "transparent" so I can set that if it is not actually going to be a container.

My difficulty is parsing the JSON. I can do one level (i.e. no containers) but I cannot get multiple levels.

I have ran my JSON through JSLint which said it was valid, but maybe it is not constructed for what I want to do.

Below please find my control and the Xpage that calls it and passes the JSON.

[In the Xpage I am simply trying to build nested repeats. If I can do that I think I can pretty easily make the navigator.]

CC

```
<xc:ccMenu
    xp:key="facetMenu">
    <xc:this.configuration><![CDATA[#{javascript:return 

[
{
   "cntNme":   "Top Menu 1",
   "cntType":  "1",
   "cntMnu":   
               {
               "mnuNme":

                    [
                        { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                        { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                        { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                        { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                    ]

               }

},

{
   "cntNme":   "Top Menu 2",
   "cntType":  "1",
   "cntMnu":

               {
               "mnuNme":

                        [
                        { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                        { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                        { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                        { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                    ]


               }

},

{
   "cntNme":   "Top Menu 3",
   "cntType":  "1",
   "cntMnu":

               {
               "mnuNme":

                                        [
                        { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                        { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                        { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                        { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                    ]
              }

}
]

}]]></xc:this.configuration>
</xc:ccMenu>
```

Xpage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <!--https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26168228/xpages-custom-control-with-custom-property-group-that-allows-multiple-instances-->
        <xp:panel
            tagName="h4">
            <xp:repeat
                id="repeat1"
                rows="30"
                disableOutputTag="true"
                value="#{compositeData.configuration}"
                var="var"
                indexVar="idx">
                <br></br>
                <xp:text
                    id="computedField1"
                    value="#{var.cntNme}"
                    disableTheme="true">
                </xp:text>
                <xp:panel
                    tagName="ul">
                    <xp:repeat
                        id="repeat2"
                        rows="30"
                        disableOutputTag="true"
                        value="#{var.cntNme}"
                        var="var2"
                        indexVar="idx">
                        <br></br>
                        <xp:text
                            id="computedField3"
                            disableTheme="true"
                            value="#{javascript:var2.cntMnu}">
                        </xp:text>
                        <br></br>
                    </xp:repeat>
                </xp:panel>
            </xp:repeat>
        </xp:panel>
<xp:view>
```

Comment: may be you need first convert it to an JsonObject,https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEUEX_2.0.3/com.ibm.javaeuc.doc/com/ibm/json/java/JSONObject.html

Comment: do you need to use a repeat control? if the purpose is mere display I would settle for something different (the result are just nested lists) e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/XE6Nw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your custom control to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:panel
        tagName="h4">
        <xp:repeat
            id="repeat1"
            rows="30"
            disableOutputTag="true"
            value="#{compositeData.configuration}"
            var="var"
            indexVar="idx">
            <br></br>
            <xp:text
                id="computedField1"
                value="#{var.cntNme}"
                disableTheme="true">
            </xp:text>
            <xp:panel
                tagName="ul">
                <xp:repeat
                    id="repeat2"
                    rows="30"
                    disableOutputTag="true"
                    value="#{var.cntMnu.mnuNme}"
                    var="var2"
                    indexVar="idx">
                    <xp:text
                        id="computedField3"
                        disableTheme="true"
                        value="#{javascript:var2.type}">
                    </xp:text>
                    <br></br>
                </xp:repeat>
            </xp:panel>
        </xp:repeat>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

I changed the following lines:

```
                    value="#{var.cntMnu.mnuNme}"

                        value="#{javascript:var2.type}">

</xp:view>
```

XPage's repeat control works perfect with JavaScript's Objects and Arrays. There is no need to convert it so something else...

Answer (score 0):

As a more basic example, you might want to look at XPages Help Application on OpenNTF. I created JSON to pass into a dijit.Tree control to create a hierarchical menu structure. It's worth bearing in mind the JSON was created manually for that and was before I knew about JsonJavaObject and JsonParser classes created by IBM (possibly before they were created, since this pre-dates Connections mail integration).